# Python setting a extra "/" or "\" to os.join for file path without doing a +

Tags: python, os.path

I have a some code to code to a file path, take that as the executable point aka CD command in shell and then execute the command for that directory part.

Normally, I use OS.PATH.JOIN to create file path but I noticed it still creates an invalid file path because there seems to be / missing initialising it.

So how to solve this I did the following

file_path = "/" + os.path.join("sys","bus","w1","devices","Othervariable")

But is there not a way that I do not have add that / tot my string contention?

**Of note to hide some context and to safeguard some company info of what I am using it for some data is classified and replaced with flavor text.**

```
file_path = "/" + os.path.join("sys","bus","w1","devices","Other variable")
command_txt_file = "txtfile command"
path_to_file = os.path.join(file_path,command_txt_file)
os.chdir(file_path)
Commandvariable = os.system("cat Commandvariable")

with open(path_to_file) as f:
    contents = f.read()
reading = float(contents)
CommandVariable = Commandconvertfucntion(reading)
return CommandVariable
```

Technically, I should do "/sys" in my join path but I am asking to be curious because there is difference in windows and Linux. If I do this in theory, it should not work for Windows. **Yes I know I cannot use these commands in Windows because windows does not have I2C wire1**. It is purely theoretical if I want to execute a similar command where such a situation shows itself.

Comment: not an answer to your question, but *if and when* you have to use `/`, use `os.sep` instead, as it's the os agnostic way...

Comment: If you need information removed effectively, the only way is to flag for a moderator and ask them to do it for you. Vandalising your post does not achieve what you need and is not appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the os separator (`os.sep`), this way it will work with both Linux and Windows paths.

Example for Windows:

```
import os
>>> f = os.path.join(os.sep,'something','subfolder')
>>> f
'\\something\\subfolder'
>>> f = os.path.join('something','subfolder')
>>> f
'something\\subfolder'
```

The resulted path can be used with `os.chdir(file_path)` if the folders already exist.